# can freemarker do second replacement

Tags: freemarker

Usually i use this type of data in freemarker:

```
(root)  
|  
+- website = "StackOverflow"  
|  
+- href = "http://stackoverflow.com"  
|  
+- label = "my favorite website."
```

but today,a java programmer give me a model like this:

```
(root)  
|  
+- website = "StackOverflow"  
|  
+- href = "http://stackoverflow.com${dir}"  
|  
+-  label = "my favorite website"  
|  
+- dir = "/questions/ask"
```

And he wants me to show dir's value in the final page.
The template:

```
${label}<a href="${href}" >${website}</a>
```

i suggested him to write a template like this

```
${label}<a href="${href}${dir}" >${website}</a>
```

but he dont want to do like this.I want to ask if there any way to realize this requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
${label}<a href="<@href?interpret/>" >${website}</a>
```

this is the answer